# Lambda's and proc's names

Tags: ruby, terminology

Is there reason why `lambda` is called lambda and `proc` is called proc?
As fair I remember both are anonymous functions... and that's where similarities with Lambdas ends.  They are not taking 1 argument like lambdas from Haskell.

Why one is called lambda where both can be equally called lambda?
Why someone used name "proc" for naming one and "lambda" for naming second?

ps. They both are in a one class, `Proc`. There is method `lambda?` that shows if it is *lambda*.

Comment: I had been asked the same kind of question in one of my interview, but I couldn't answer. Today I will learn it from there. Thanks to bringing it up here. :) +1

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043181/ruby-lambda-vs-proc-new

Comment: @TonyHopkinson No it is not... I think, at-least the one you referenced..

Comment: It's duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740046/whats-the-difference-between-a-proc-and-a-lambda-in-ruby

Comment: ``Proc.new`` and ``proc`` are equivalent, for the difference to ``lambda`` check the link I've posted.

Comment: Hence the question mark. :) It does detail the differences between Proc and Lambda though, and to be honest why they called proc proc and lambda lambda is not usually of that much interest, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: @lipanski no, it's not duplicate. I wasn't asking about difference between `lambda` and `proc` (`->` and 'Proc.new`). I was asking about reason they call lambda - lambda and proc - proc.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson see above comment

Answer (score 3):

In ruby, lambdas are a special kind of Proc objects whose behavior mimics that of a method. In particular, it'll respect arity: if you give it the wrong number of args, it spits an error.

See this answer (to an unrelated question) for colorful examples of how they differ:

[Why does Hash#select and Hash#reject pass a key to a unary block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861502/why-does-hashselect-and-hashreject-pass-a-key-to-a-unary-block/20862285#20862285)

Replying to the comment: lamba and proc both product a Proc object. The only differences are the above-mentioned behavior when it comes to arity, and what happens with a return statement (see the related link in the question's comments).

As for why they're named that way, look no further than it being Matz' choice imo: this was the most natural. He defined what he means by that in an interview:

> Everyone has an individual background. Someone may come from Python, someone else may come from Perl, and they may be surprised by different aspects of the language. Then they come up to me and say, 'I was surprised by this feature of the language, so Ruby violates the principle of least surprise.' Wait. Wait. The principle of least surprise is not for you only. The principle of least surprise means principle of least ***my*** surprise. And it means the principle of least surprise after you learn Ruby very well. For example, I was a C++ programmer before I started designing Ruby. I programmed in C++ exclusively for two or three years. And after two years of C++ programming, it still surprises me.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)#Philosophy

In that light, note how a lambda behaves very much like a method, and in this respect qualifies as a (anonymous) *function*. Whereas a proc does not. Naming the first of these "lambda" seems like a natural choice (to me, anyway), whereas the second wouldn't due to the differences when it comes to arity and return statements.

Comment: It doesn't explain why lambda is lambda and why proc is proc etc.

Comment: Not convinced that that quote proves anything very much, beyond the Humpty Dumpty reason: “When I use a word, it means just what I choose it to mean — neither more nor less.”

Comment: @DonalFellows: if you've a better quote from Matz, please add it as an answer. Because insofar as I'm aware, lambda vs proc as a nomenclature is just as arbitrary as having decided to use e.g. Decimal or FixNum. And yes: the humpty dumpty quote is just as apt as a reply to OP: there *is* no reason beyond whatever random thoughts were in Matz' head that day.

Comment: @DonalFellows: I did my best to add what *might* feel natural about the convention.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: haha! Very illustrative way to put it. :-)

Comment: Denis, are you saying a lambda is (l)ike (a) (m)ethod, (b)oth (d)emand (a)rity?

Comment: What qualify both, `lambda`/`->` and `proc`/`Proc.new`, to be an instances of class `Proc`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there reason why lambda is called lambda and proc is called proc?

Let's see what happened with call to `proc`, and `lambda` in *ruby 1.8.7*:

```
aa = lambda {|a| nil }
# => #<Proc:0xb7351850@(irb):6>
aa.call
# warning: multiple values for a block parameter (0 for 1)
# => nil 

aa = proc {|a| nil }
# => #<Proc:0xb73451cc@(irb):10> 
aa.call
# warning: multiple values for a block parameter (0 for 1)
```

As we can see, there is no difference between the `proc`, and `lambda` in Ruby. I believe that the `proc` had appeared in `Ruby` at first. Because it just alias to `Proc.new`, which creates the `Proc` object. Then the `lambda` had added into *ruby*, because the [Lambda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#Ruby) is the so called anonymous function in computer programming area, and the developers could see in the language well-known name for that fucntion class.

Let's see that happened with the operators in *ruby 1.9.1*:

```
aa = lambda {|a| nil }
# => #<Proc:0x8054340@(irb):1 (lambda)> 
aa.call
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
from (irb):2:in `call'
from (irb):2
from /home/malo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p431/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
aa = proc {|a| nil }
# => #<Proc:0x8319bf0@(irb):3> 
aa.call
# => nil
```

As we can see, in *ruby 1.9.2* (I guess since *ruby 1.9*) was added attribute *lambda* into `Proc` instance saying that the anonymouns function will not accept the wrong argument amount. So passing the *0* arguments into *1* required raises the `ArgumentError` exception. While the passing the *0* arguments into *1* required for the `proc` object silently drops the unnecessary argument.

As you know from *ruby 1.9.1* was added `->` as an alias to argumentless `lambda` operator:

```
 aa = -> { nil }
 # => #<Proc:0x8056ffc@(irb):1 (lambda)> 
 aa = -> {|a| nil }
 # SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected '|'
     aa = -> {|a| nil }
              ^
```

Comment: @Darek-Nedza has any answer been helpful?